# What is the meaning of returning a function from another function?

Tags: javascript, function, nested, closures, lexical-scope

What is the meaning of returning a function from another function in javascript. Is this is same as if I call a function which is in another function

```js
function fun(c){
    let a=3;
     return function(){
        return a+c;
    }
}
let add=fun(2);
console.log(add);
```

. And my second question is why this add variable is a function.

Comment: You added the `closure` tag, so you do know what's going on?

Comment: "*What is the meaning of returning a function*" basically answers "*why this add variable is a function*".

Comment: @georg yeah..inner function preserving the value of a and c which is the concept of closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the object which you are returning is the function.
In this context, variable add contains a reference to the function which you have to invoke.

Answer (score 1):

This is called currying. It allows you to apply arguments to functions one by one.
Example:

```js
const add = a => b => a + b // Function that takes `a` and returns a function that adds `a` to `b`
const addThree = add(3) // bind `a` to 3. This is a function that takes `b` and adds 3 to it
console.log(addThree(1)) // now `b` is 1, it's gonna be added to `a` and return the final value
```

There's a lot of literature about currying and partial application. Google is your friend